# Automatic base URL for scraped images from other sites

Tags: php, web-scraping, base-url

Using HTML DOM Parser, I am getting the image (either og:image or first avaialble image) from a external website,

```
$site_image = ($html->find('meta[property="og:image"]', 0)) ? ($html->find('meta[property="og:image"]', 0)->content) : "";
// If og:image tag is not present get the first image
if($site_image=="") $site_image = ($html->find('img', 0)) ? ($site_image = $html->find('img', 0)->src) : "";
```

The code works well for retrieving images from websites, except **google**.

[image: Google source code]

As you see in the image, Google is using images without the base URL. In PHP, is there any possiblity to get 'src' with it's correct base URL?

So it should be **http://www.google.co.in/images/nav_logo242.png**

Comment: Why not just prepend the Base URL if there isn't one?

Comment: Why not simply prepend it when using Google?

Comment: Some URL's have "." or "../" with the `src`, and some sites have `<base>` tag too, so probably appending the URL will not work, I guess.

Comment: Stripping . or .. is not an issue however I am wondering is there any better way to get the complete URL!